# Unable to update individual items in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to update some information in my Django application but I am getting this error "Cannot assign "9": "Reservation.table" must be a "Tables" instance".

I have tried so manual method also but it still same error.

**Error**: Cannot assign "9": "Reservation.table" must be a "Tables" instance

views.py

```
@login_required
def UpdateReservation(request, pk):
    table_exists = get_object_or_404(Reservation, id=pk)
    form = ReservationForm(instance=table_exists)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST, instance=table_exists)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = ReservationForm(request.POST, instance=table_exists)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('view_reservations')
                messages.success(request, "successfully updated table")
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, "dashboard/super/landlord/update_reserve.html", context)
```

models.py

```
class Reservation(models.Model):

    status_choices = (
        ("pending", "pending"), 
        ("confirmed", "confirmed")
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    people = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    time = models.TimeField()
    date_reserved = models.DateField()
    date_booked = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=status_choices, default="confirmed")
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
    table = models.ForeignKey(Tables, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

forms.py

```
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    time = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'timepicker',
                                      'class': 'input-group',
                                      'placeholder': '12:00:AM'}))
    date_reserved = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'yyyy-mm-dd',
               'id': 'datepicker'}), required=True,)
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Leave a message'}), required=True,)
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Leave a message'}), required=False,)
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Email Address'}), required=True,)
    phone = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Telephone number'}), required=True,)
    table = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'placeholder': 'Table Number'}), required=True,)

    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ['first_name', 'email', 'time', 'comment',
                  'phone', 'date_reserved', 'people', 'table']
```

template.html

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}                                   
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                {{ field|attr:'class:form-control'}}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <center><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update Reservation</button></center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form remove your table field from the field list above but keep the one in the Meta, its messing with it because the value is in Integer and you have to assign an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can not make use of an `IntegerField`, since it expects a `Table`, not an integer for `table`. You should use a `ModelChoiceField` and then use a `TextInput` as widget:

```
    table = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                   queryset=Table.objects.all()
                   widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Table Number'}),
                   required=True
               )
```